# 'There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>' that has the key 'IsWorkingID

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, exception, visual-studio-2017

I am creating an ASP.NET MVC registration form and I use dropdown list in my form, but when I hit the submit button in my view, this error occurs:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable' that has the key 'IsWorkingID'.

I tried different methods, but none are working.

This is my model:

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Field Required")]
[Display(Name = "Do you work in a medical practice?")]
public int IsWorkingID { get; set; }
```

This is my controller:

```
public class UserController : Controller
{
    // GET: User
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        try
        {
            MyDBEntities db = new MyDBEntities();

            List<WorkingDetail> list = db.WorkingDetails.ToList();
            ViewBag.WorkingDetail = new SelectList(list, "IsWorkingID", "IsWorking");

            return View();
        }
        catch (InvalidOperationException exception)
        {
             throw exception;
        }
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult SaveRecord(UserViewModel model)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return View("Index");
        }
        else
        {
            try
            {
                MyDBEntities db = new MyDBEntities();

                User userObj = new User();
                userObj.FirstName = model.FirstName;
                userObj.LastName = model.LastName;
                userObj.Email = model.Email;
                userObj.PhoneNo = model.PhoneNo;
                userObj.IsWorkingID = model.IsWorkingID;

                db.Users.Add(userObj);
                db.SaveChanges();

                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                 throw ex;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is my view:

```
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.IsWorkingID)

@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.IsWorkingID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.IsWorkingID, ViewBag.WorkingDetail as SelectList, "", new { @class = "form-control" })
```

When I fill the form properly the values stored in db but when I leave any field empty then `ViewBag` returns null value.

But it should show me the error message on form field is required instead of

> InvalidOperationException - there is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable' that has the key 'IsWorkingID'

Comment: Your code above shows you _not_ passing your model to the view; i.e. you call `return View()`, rather than `return View(list)` (or whatever the model is). Can you edit it to show how you are actually passing the model? Also show the @model line in the view.

Comment: @model UserRegistration.Models.UserViewModel this is i am passing in the view

Comment: i don't know why always viewbag.workdetail return null